# Iterative Methods for Solving Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, computer-science

I am looking for some program/package that is able to numerically solve differential equations. I am NOT looking for a procedure that starts with some initial values and evolves from the initial conditions. What I am looking for is a method such that we input an initial guess for a function that is almost a solution, then it iterates the guess to make it a better fit to the differential equation. Does such a method/program exist? (If there is such a version in python, that would be ideal).

For example, maybe I have a diff eq that describes a damped harmonic oscillator; we might input a sine wave but it modifies this to become a damped sine wave.

Comment: When you know that it's a sine function, you can directly apply the formula to find that exact solution. Why bother doing that?

Comment: You can use Picard's method, which is in this case mostly symbolic.

Comment: You are looking to fit a solution of an ODE to a given function table. I'm afraid that for numerical purposes the IVP is the most common way to specify such a solution. Nevertheless, there are multiple-shooting approaches and collocation methods, often used in combination.

Comment: maybe it is helpful to look at SINDy-type method. They generally fit differential equations to data, but probably you can use the same technique to solutions and their numerical approximation